# How do I get past this login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, watin

I need to visit several web pages every day to update a spreadsheet. I'm trying to automate the process. On one site, I can't get past the login page.
No matter what I throw at it, it says I haven't entered anything. If I type one character in and delete it, it works fine.

```
TextField UserField = FindUsernameField(UsernameField);
UserField.ClickNoWait();
UserField.MouseEnter();
UserField.Value = userID;
UserField.SetAttributeValue("aria-invalid", "false");  // has no affect, still true
string attr = UserField.GetAttributeValue("class");
attr = attr.Replace("invalid", "valid");  // fails as attr is null

UserField.KeyPress();                

TextField PasswordField = FindPasswordField(this.PasswordField);
PasswordField.Click();
PasswordField.TypeText(password);
PasswordField.Change();

FindButton(LoginButton).Click();
```

There is more error checking, but this is the basic code. As you can see below, it successfully inserts the data. But this one website doesn't acknowledge it.

[image: login failed]

The HTML for the field starts like this:

```
<input class="ods-textfield__input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="ods-input-0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" aria-labelledby="label-input-0" style="padding-left: 3rem;" type="text" placeholder="" odsInput="" data-controlname="username" _ngcontent-qwp-c11="">
```

and ends like this:

```
<input class="ods-textfield__input ng-invalid ng-touched ods-textfield__input--error ng-dirty" id="ods-input-0" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="false" aria-labelledby="label-input-0 ods-error-0" style="padding-left: 3rem;" type="text" placeholder="" odsInput="" data-controlname="username" _ngcontent-qrr-c11="">
```

I expected "required"

But if I manually enter text, I get this:

```
<input class="ods-textfield__input ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" id="ods-input-0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" aria-labelledby="label-input-0" style="padding-left: 3rem;" type="text" placeholder="" odsInput="" data-controlname="username" _ngcontent-qwp-c11="">
```

UPDATE: I tried getting the class desc and swapping ng-invalid for ng-valid, and setting invalid=false, see above for code.

Comment: Have you tried focusing the fields or removing perhaps some sort of validation `class`?

Comment: Those fields clearly have some Java Script valdiation, and it seems setup in a way that your editing is not triggering a re-evaluation.

Comment: I added Web-scraping to the Tags, as it fits there almsot perfectly. I also added ASP.NET, as people there often deal with this kind of JavaScript. Included Automated testing, I hope.

Comment: @Silvermind Focusing was the point of the Click, MouseEnter, and Keypress. Was unable to affect the class. Open to other suggestions on focus.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, clearly. When I posted I was unable to access the JS. I've found that now. But it still doesn't hit the breakpoints.